# Django python, differences between self.request and '%s' % self.request

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm getting parameters through GET or POST.

On the book I'm reading,
there's

`Word = '%s' % self.request.POST['word']`

I wonder whether there's a specific reason for that.
I mean why not like this just simply?

`Word = self.request.POST['word']`

Comment: It guarantees you end up with a string, although just calling `str` with the word would be more intentful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw away this book, if it tells you to capitalize first letter of the variables and not to use:

```
self.request.POST.get('word', '')
```

Comment: Are there any differences between using '%s' and not?

Comment: No, hence it's an unnecessary addition.

Comment: No worries. Which book is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no difference between the two line.